# how to make a sticky headerTableView while having numerous headers in sections?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

A goal of mine is to have an appearing/disappearing headerTableView - show on scroll up, hide on scroll down. I have tried setting tableView style to plain but then my section view headers are sticky and not just the headerTableView. Does anyone have an idea how to have an always showing/disappearing headerTableView regardless of scroll position (not just when I'm on top)?

Comment: Keep track of the collpased/uncollapsed section states with an array of a dictionary.

Comment: do you have any bit of code? Not trying to go for the lowest hanging fruit, but I'm not sure I know how to